# Change Access report RecordSource and then OutputTo PDF from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop

How would I change a Microsoft Access report's `RecordSource` property from a C# Windows Forms handler, using `Office.Interop` code?

I need to ***silently*** save the report as a PDF, using `AccessApp.DoCmd.OutputTo(...)` without any Parameter prompts from Access.  So I want to temporarily change `RecordSource` to an query defined by the form's code, silently save the PDF report, and then change `RecordSource` back to a default.

I've tried something like `AccessApp.Reports["Report Name"].RecordSource` but I get errors!

Is there a better way to do this than the way I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me (tested with Access 2010):

```csharp
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenReport(
        "Report1", 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcView.acViewDesign);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Report rpt = accessApp.Reports["Report1"];
rpt.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ID<=3";

accessApp.DoCmd.OutputTo(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcOutputObjectType.acOutputReport,
        "",
        "PDF Format (*.pdf)",
        @"C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\zzzTest.pdf",
        false,
        null,
        null,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcExportQuality.acExportQualityPrint);

// now close the report without saving the change to the RecordSource property
accessApp.DoCmd.Close(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acReport,
        "Report1",
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcCloseSave.acSaveNo);
```

Comment: May I please give you a kiss!?